Sentence ending ど?
I've encountered the following sentence where an elderly woman is talking about a horse, which seems to use ど as a particle twice.
知らない奴が近づくと けっとばされるど この前もけっとばされて ２人死んだど！
My current understanding of this is:
(If a stranger gets close, they get kicked hard. The last two people who were kicked died!)
But I'm not sure what ど is supposed to be doing here. I've tried searching to see if this is a part of 老人語 or a dialect, but haven't had any luck so far.

That's a local dialect from somewhere

I suspect it is a plain quotative と. I observed in 老人語, unvoiced consonants tend to become voiced consonants.

@weeab00 What 老人語 are you thinking of? Can you give examples?

@Angelos You can find few examples when you read じいさんばあさん若返る.

ど is a sentence-end particle found in many dialects. It's similar in purpose to (だ)ぞ or (だ)よ.

知らんど！とか悪人ど！という(ど！)が語尾につく方言は何処の県でしょうか？

方言終助詞「ど」は、おおよそ、東北地方と鹿児島県に存在すると言えそうです。以上は私がネットを徘徊してひっかき集めた情報ですが、この回答の直上に別に投稿された別な回答の内容を見ると、どうやら、山陰山陽地方にも存在するところがあるようで、さらに九州北部にも存在する可能性がありそうです。意外に存在範囲が広いようです。



From my personal experience, ど is used in a part of Shikoku, too. This is not stereotypical 老人語.
